# Japanese light novel. Main character is banished, gets a goblin wife and builds a country of monsters

Tags: story-identification, novel

Mainly, our mc gets banished from his noble house due to..... I think useless abilities? He was forced to go to the underworld, where it's rumored to be extremely dangerous due to monsters only roaming there. At the start, he tries to start a farm in the underground to sustain himself, then he first comes in contact with a goblin village, where he gets a goblin waifu. Later on, a slime queen is introduced too. Basically he gets a country built out of monsters I think, step by step. His brothers, at a certain point of story goes sent down to the underground to investigate, fights the mc and they either got killed or get a warning and sent back to the household via humiliation. One of his abilities is to spawn monsters out of nowhere to fight for him, I think.

This ain't confirmed, the mc may have came from earth.

Comment: A main character whose abilities at first seem useless but prove to actually be overpowered? How do they come up with these plotlines? Genius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Hazure Skill “Gacha” de Tsuihou Sareta Ore wa, Wagamama Osananajimi wo Zetsuen Shi Kakusei Suru ~ Bannou Cheat Skill wo Getto Shite, Mezase Rakuraku Saikyou Slow Life!~*](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/hazure-skill-gacha-de-tsuihou-sareta-ore-wa-wagamama-osananajimi-wo-zetsuen-shi-kakusei-suru-bannou-cheat-skill-wo-getto-shite-mezase-rakuraku-saikyou-slow-life/) by Kijima Ryuuta and 木嶋隆太.

> Crest was born as the fifth son of a duke. However, as the fifth son, he was in no position to talk. His childhood friend and also his fiancée, Ellis, treated him just like a s*ave. And on Crest’s coming-of-age ceremony, he received a skill called “Gacha.” Yet, he wasn’t able to learn how to use it and was banished away from his home. Banished into the forest full of monsters, Crest began to understand the power “Gacha.” And then, Crest made up his mind. He will definitely survive and get back on his feet.

This is the series name, and I found out the answer from someone in novelupdates

Answer (score -2):

I think its Banished from the Heros Party. Sounds similiar.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe the aspects of this work that match the details in the question?

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't.